# "Could not resolve" errors with wicd-curses static configuration

Tags: networking, internet, wicd-curses

I'm running a [minimal Raspbian build](http://www.linuxsystems.it/raspbian-wheezy-armhf-raspberry-pi-minimal-image/) (desktop GUI removed) and have connected to the network by `wicd-curses`.  I've configured it with a static IP, and am now on the network and can ssh in.  But the Pi is unable to connect to the internet - when I run `apt-update` I get `Could not resolve 'archive.raspbian.org'`.  Same for other `apt-get` calls.  I think the problem is in the wicd-curses setup.   Grateful for assistance.  The setup configuration is:

```
[X] Use Static IPs
IP:     192.168.1.25
Netmask:255.255.255.0
Gateway:192.168.1.254

[X] Use Static DNS                                                                         [ ] Use global DNS servers
DNS domain:
Search domain:
DNS server 1:
DNS server 2:
DNS server 3:

[X] Use DHCP Hostname
DHCP Hostname: raspi

[ ] Use these settings for all networks sharing this essid
[X] Automatically connect to this network
[X] Use Encryption
WPA 1/2 (Hex [0-9/A-F])    vvv
Key: **********

F10:OK                                                                                     ESC:Cancel
Connected to BTHub3-GH38"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK> at 100% (IP: 192.168.1.25)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm running the same set-up--headless Pi with wicd-curses used to establish a static IP. To set up DNS I use these settings:

```
[X] Use Static IPs
IP: 192.168.1.207
Netmask:255.255.255.0
Gateway:192.168.1.1

[X] Use Static DNS                     [ ] Use global DNS servers
DNS domain:
Search domain:google.com
DNS server 1:        8.8.8.8
DNS server 2:        8.8.4.4
DNS server 3:

[X] Use DHCP Hostname
DHCP Hostname: raspberrypi

[X] Use these settings for all networks sharing this essid
[X] Automatically connect to this network
[X] Use Encryption
WPA 1/2 (Hex [0-9/A-F])     vvv
Key: *************
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are telling it to use a static DNS server list, but are not actually setting any DNS servers. You should either make DNS non static or enter your DNS Servers' IP Address. You could even use @Scot's suggection and use Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

You should set DNS Server to some public DNS.  For example, try Google's public DNS - 8.8.8.8.

Comment: This question would be a lot better with a bit of explanation. As it stands right now, you provide no information as to **how** the OP would set the DNS server to Google's. Provide that and your answer will be a lot better.

Comment: Common RPI? That is a bit harsh. Its pretty easy to make the connection that DNS goes into DNS.